# What if K in K-Fold Cross Validation is Too Small?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, dataset, data-science, k-fold

What are the consequences of using a K value which is **too** small in comparison to the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `K` specifies the number of folds you plan to split the dataset into. Smaller values of `K` means that the dataset is split into fewer parts, but each part contains a larger percentage of the dataset.

Taking a dataset with 100 rows.

- 2 fold cross validation - Each fold will contain 50 rows.
- 10 fold cross validation - Each fold will contain 10 rows.

This way, when training, the 10 fold cross validation will have a 90-10 train-test split, where as the 2 fold cross validation will have a 50-50 train test split.

Making use of more folds, will present the model with more data to train on, but will required way more time as it has to train and validate `K` separate times.

Answer (score 0):

K in K-fold Cross-validation indicates that in how many equal parts we want to split our training data and perform re-sampling K times on the given limited training data.

**Positives:**

- A good model can be developed even with limited data.
- We get the optimal value of our hyper-parameter (k in KNN, alpha in Naive Bayes, etc) which gives us the best performance metric (Accuracy, AUC, Precision, etc).

**Negatives:**

- As we are training the model K times, the time it takes to compute the optimal hyperparameter increases by K-times.